# Swift Nested try inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a requirement in the below way

```
enum CustomError1: Error {
    case errorA
}

enum CustomError2: Error {
    case errorA
}

public func func1(completion: @escaping () -> Void) throws {
    //some code
    if #somecondition {
        throw CustomError1.errorA
    }
    completion()
}

public func func2(completion: @escaping () -> Void) throws {
    //some code
    if #somecondition {
        throw CustomError2.errorA
    }
    completion()
}


func result() {
    do {
        try func1() {
            try self.func2 (){

            }
        }
    } catch {

    }
}
```

the result function gives an error as below

```
Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void'
```

That is because the func1 and func2 are giving different type of Error.

Due to this I need to write another `do catch` inside the first closure as below

```
func result() {
    do {
        try func1() {
            do {
                try self.func2 (){

                }
            } catch {

            }
        }
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this kind of nested try catches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the argument to `func1` is typed as `escaping () -> Void`. That means you cannot throw inside the function you pass as that argument. You would need to have typed this as `escaping () throws -> Void`.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum CustomError1: Error {
    case errorA
}

enum CustomError2: Error {
    case errorA
}

public func func1(completion: @escaping () throws -> Void) throws {
    //some code
    if true {
        throw CustomError1.errorA
    }
    try completion()
}

public func func2(completion: @escaping () throws -> Void) throws {
    //some code
    if true {
        throw CustomError2.errorA
    }
    try completion()
}


func result() {
    do {
        try func1(completion: {
            try func2 (completion: {

            })
        })
    } catch {

    }
}
```

I wouldn't suggest using throw with completions. The better way is using better completion implementation. Something like this:

```
public func func1(completion: @escaping (Error?) throws -> Void) throws {
    //some code
    if true {
        completion(CustomError1.errorA)
    }
   completion(nil)
}
```